# How to write a cupy user-defined kernel function to calculate the segmented sum

Tags: numpy, cupy

I use the following function now, but I don't think it works, but I can't understand the description of the cupy kernel definition. This function is very memory intensive and time-consuming when it comes to huge data.

```
def cupy_sum(self, bins):
    bidx = cupy.cumsum(bins) -1,
    return cupy.diff(cupy.r_[0, cupy.cumsum(self)[bidx]])
```

Refer to other examples and write the following code, do not know if there is a problem.

```
sum_section_kernel = cp.ElementwiseKernel(
'raw T bins, raw T dats',
'float32 out',
'''
T bin_f = bins[i  ];
T bin_l = bins[i+1];
T biv   = 0;
for(size_t j=bin_f; j<bin_l; j++){
  biv += dats[j];
}        
out = biv; 
''',
'summe')

a = cp.array([4, 3, 5], dtype=cp.float32)
b = cp.array([1, 1, 1.1, 1,   2, 2, 2,   3, 3, 3, 3, 3], dtype=cp.float32)
y = cp.empty(3, dtype=cp.float32)

a = cp.r_[0,a.cumsum()]
out = sum_section_kernel(a, b, y)
print(out)

> [ 4.100  6.000  15.000]
```

Answer (score 0):

The example has been put in the above, and the speed has not been improved, but I think there is still the advantage of saving memory.